# Need Suggestion for my app

Tags: c#

I want to show an loading image when i launch my desktop application. can anybody tell me how to show this in C#? Results required as happens in visual studio 2005/2008 when we launch this application.

Comment: IIRC there is some SplashScreen template?

Comment: For WPF there is a SplashScreen API. You could easily add a bitmap based splash. It's .NET 4 I think, and I do not know if you can use it with WinForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually a splash screen. Look at this codeproject article. It explains really well how you should do this.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/prettygoodsplashscreen.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What i did in my previous project was, that make the Form1 (display form) and make it wait for a while, then close it after that launch the Form2 which is the actual application.

But that was way back when i was a fresher. Now what i might do is, have a Form1 which ill launch and in the backgroundworker do all major UI processing work such as if any loading of data needs to be done, etc stuffs and keep every thing ready in memory. Then ill close the Form1 or make it hide or invisible and launch the Form2 which is the main app form and pass all the information required to it.